# $l^r \subset l^p$ and is it even a subspace

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

It is true that for $r<p$ and $r,p \in [1,\infty)$ we have that $l^r \subset l^p$. Is it true that $l^r$ cannot be isomorphic to a subspace of $l^p$?

Comment: Google "Pitt's Theorem".

Comment: To be isomorphic as real vector spaces, it suffices to have the same dimension.  However isomorphism of normed linear spaces usually entails more than this, a mapping for which the norm of the image vector is uniformly bounded below and above by a norm in the domain (so stronger than mere continuity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $1<p\neq q<\infty$ then $\ell_p \not\! \hookrightarrow \ell_q$ and $\ell_q\not \!\hookrightarrow \ell_p$. The simbol " $X\not \!\hookrightarrow$ Y" in this case denotes that $Y$ has not a subspace isomorphic to $X$.

Look this in the "HANDBOOK OF THE GEOMETRY OF BANACH S PACES", Vol 1, W.B. JOHNSON and 
J. LINDENSTRAUSS, Theorem 26 (a), pg. 142.

Comment: and why is that so?

Comment: Lipschitz, one way to see that is Pitt's theorem. You can also use type/cotype arguments to see that non-existence of isomorphisms extends to the spaces $L_p(\mu)$, $L_q(\mu)$ for $p\neq q$.

Comment: Look this in the "HANDBOOK OF THE GEOMETRY OF BANACH S PACES", Vol 1, W.B. JOHNSON and J. LINDENSTRAUSS, Theorem 26 (a), pg. 142.

Answer (score 0):

To see the inclusion, suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|^r < \infty$.  Then $|a_n| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  So, by discarding at most finitely many of the terms if necessary, we assume that $|a_n| < 1$ for all $n$.  But then we have that $|a_n|^r > |a_n|^p$ since $p > r$.  So...

Comment: The inclusion was a fact I mentioned, not a question. The question is about a possible isomorphism.